# Big O Clarification

Tags: functions

Show that $\dfrac{x^2+1}{x+1}$ is $O(x)$.
The book says this function simplifies to $\dfrac{x-1+2}{x+1}$.
Can you explain to me the process in which $x^2+1 = x-1+2$?

Thank you.

Comment: The book means $x^2 -1+2$.

Comment: Can you explain how to simplified it?

Comment: Add one, subtract one - the add zero trick is powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} &=\frac{x^2-1+2}{x+1} \\
&=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)+2}{x+1}\\
&=x-1+\frac{2}{x+1} \\
&\leq x-1+1, \text{ if } x\geq 1 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, actually,
$$
\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} = x-1+\frac{2}{x+1}
$$